# Displaying the results from a SQL Select Statment

Tags: c#, .net, sql, entity-framework-4

Right problem I've been trying to sort for ages now!

I'm trying to display the result from a SQL select command and display this information to my view. I can't simple use EntityFramework, not from what I can see anyway, to do the command because I am bringing in data from 2 different tables and displaying as one, this is for a report.

this is the sql command I need to run.

```
select FirstName, LastName,
(select count(*) from Orders o where U.userID = o.CreatedByUserID and ProductID = 1) as ProductCount
from Users U
order by UserID
```

Is there anything I can do to run this command? I'd be willing to try a EntityFramwork way of doing it if I can't run the SQL directly.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What *have* you tried and failed?

Comment: "Yes" is not an answer to "what".

Comment: sorry miss read! - i've been trying this and it hasn't been working for me. the 'ExecuteSelect' method wont run for some reason http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/374195/How-to-use-SqlDataReader-result-in-a-Layered-Archi

Comment: Have you tried plain simple `SqlCommand.ExecuteDataReader`?

Comment: yea, but my main problem is now displaying that data on the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* use EF (or another ORM solution). There is clearly a relationship between the orders and the users: `U.userID = o.CreatedByUserID`. You can just retrieve the users, and then access `user.Orders.Count` to get the "missing" value.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ctx is your Context try

```
var q=from u in ctx.users
      join x in ctx.orders.Where(y=>y.ProductID==1).GroupBy(y => y.CreatedByUserID) 
      on u.UserID equals x.Key into joined_orders
from o in joined_orders.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new {
        FirstName=u.FirstName, 
        LastName=u.LastName, 
        Count=o.Count()
      };
```

This assumes that you don't have any Relationships defined in your model, otherwise you could just use

```
var q=from u in ctx.users
      select new { 
        FirstName=u.FirstName,
        LastName=u.LastName,
        Count=o.Count(x=>x.ProductID==1)
       };
```